# Can't login with encrypted password from database

Tags: php, md5, password-hash, cryptographic-hash-function

I can encrypt my password with md5 by simply wrapping it around -

```
$Password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

The encrypted password gets stored in the database successfully when the user registers. However when i want to login with the plain text password, it decides not too. How can I solve this issue?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {

$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];



$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Email);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Password);

$query ="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Email = '{$Email}' AND Password =   '{$Password}'";


$select_customer_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$select_customer_query)

die("QUERY FAILED". mysqli_error($connection));

}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_customer_query)) {

$Email_db = $row['Email'];
$Password_db = $row['Password'];
$Firstname_db = $row['First_Name'];
$Lastname_db = $row['Last_Name'];
$string ="logged in as";
$logoutlink = '/ <a href="includes/back/logout.php">Logout</a>';



} 


if ($Email_db == $Email || $Password_db == $Password  ) {


header("Location: ../../index.php");



$_SESSION['FirstName'] = $Firstname_db;
$_SESSION['LastName'] = $Lastname_db;
$_SESSION['string'] = $string;
$_SESSION['logoutlink'] = $logoutlink;


} 


?>
```

Comment: you're not MD5'ing the password again before passing it into the SQL query for comparison...

Comment: and how may i do this?

Comment: Change $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Password); to $Password = md5($Password);

Comment: If your password in DB is encrypted and you compare it to the one that is not encrypted, they do not tend to match

Comment: HI Garry Welding, what about the $connection... i need this variable. So your saying this - $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Email); $Password = md5($Password);

Comment: Without seeing what exactly is being inserted into the database when a user registers, it's difficult to do anything but *guess*. If you encrypt it with `md5()` (which you really shouldn't), all you need to do is how the answers below suggests.

Comment: @steve MD5 is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function. It is also insecure, at a minimum use SHA256 for as hash function. But you really need to use PBKDF2 or bcrypt with a random salt to protect passwords.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `md5()` the password before comparing, you'll need to compare the `md5()` version:

```
$Password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Currently, you are comparing `$Password_db == $Password`

```
$Password = $_POST['password']; //Not md5() hashed
$Password_db = $row['Password']; //md5() hashed
```

Just a tip, you should't use `md5()` as it's not secure.

Comment: @steve If this doesn't work (which shouldn't be the case), try echoing out the values `$Password` and `$Password_db` to double check the values.

Comment: Thank you Luweigi. Which encryption method do you recommend?

Comment: @steve I would recommend `password_verify()` as detailed in Scott's answer

Comment: While this answers the question, it is still not good advise. MD5 should not be recommended to hash user passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of what you're doing, to be secure, you'll want a workflow that looks something like this:

1. Grab the user ID and password-hash from the database, for the given customer.
2. If `password_verify($password, $storedHash)`, proceed.

Don't outsource your password check to the SELECT query. Don't store plaintext passwords. Don't use MD5 for password protection. Don't call MD5 encryption.

Recommended reading:

- [How to safely store your users' passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) (use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`)
- [How to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2224584) (use prepared statements)
- [The correct cryptography terminology](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) (MD5 is not an encryption algorithm)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I got it working with password_verify().

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$Password = $_POST['password'];
```

Need to change to:

```
$Password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Because you need compare encrypt passowrds.

Comment: That's not encryption.